# Where does Apple state 30% transaction fee for paid apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have read some blog posts stating Apple would charge 30% transaction fee of paid apps. I want to release a paid app, but I just want to make sure officially where apple states that 30% transaction fee? anyone with that link? I searched the developer.apple.com, but I cannot find it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple/AppStore policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the right hand side of the link below, it says developers get 70% of sales.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html